# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

**Question**: How to compute 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}?
$$

Here is what I have tried so far:

Define $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}$ for every index $n$, $\{{s_n}\}$ is monotonically increasing, $\{{s_n}\}$ converges because it is monotone and bounded.

$$
0\leq s_n\leq \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \frac{\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{2}-0}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1.
$$

Bounded monotonically increasing sequence converges to its $\sup$. Thus $\sup \{{s_n}\}\leq 1$. How can I find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k 2^k}$ or equivalently $\sup \{{s_n}\}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with, or able to calculate, the Taylor series for $\log(1-x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The Taylor series for $\log(1 - x)$ is
$$\log(1 - x) \sim -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}.$$

Comment: So the answer is $ln 2 \sim 0.693147$. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Strictly speaking, you should check that $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is inside the radius of convergence of the power series, but that's not too bad.